# Is mysql_insert_id thread safe?

Tags: mysql, c

I'm using MySQL C API to build a db client application, and i need to get the last autoincremented value in a INSERT statement, so mysql_insert_id does.

But this client is multithreaded and a piece of code like this:

> mysql_query(conn, query_string);
> value = mysql_insert_id(conn);

I don't know what will it return, this query autogenerated id or something else. Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) mysql_insert_id will return an id of the last successful insert on the **current connection**.

So if you use the same connection for several threads it will not be thread safe.

Comment: Ops, so i'm screwed, I can't set a lock there :/