# How to insert and select data in the same SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I used query like this

```
INSERT INTO coins VALUES (NULL, '$user_ID', '$title', NOW())
```

now later in this same script page, I need to use value coin_ID that I just inserted in the query above. It's auto increment value so I added NULL.

how can I use this coin_ID in this same page, after I ran some checking with PHP?

thanks

Comment: and I forgot to mention, I'm going to use that coin_ID to select linked columns in another table

Comment: I get this error when I use that function http://i.imgur.com/f34EJ.png can it be issue with permissions?

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) in PHP or [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html) in mysql

Answer (score 2):

See [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which database driver you are using with PHP. If you are using the standard mysql functions you can use the [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function:

```
$coin_id = mysql_insert_id()
```

If you are using PHP's PDO then you can use the [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)() method:

```
$coin_id = $DB->lastInsertId()
```

If you are using a database that supports the [RETURNS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-insert.html) sql keyword (such as postgres) then you can do it in one query. MySQL doesn't support it however.

```
INSERT INTO coins VALUES (NULL, '$user_ID', '$title', NOW()) RETURNING coin_id;
```

If you edit your post to include the method of database interaction that you are using, we can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to retrive last inserted ID.

Answer (score 1):

`$coin_ID = mysql_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) via the PHP `mysql_insert_id` function.

Comment: Is this function actually safe in the face of there being another thread/process that INSERTs into the database between when the current context inserts, and then runs this function? If not, seems like that'll lead to subtle corruptions/errors that are very hard to track down!

Comment: @Kitsune `LAST_INSERT_ID` is safe in a transaction, and `mysql_insert_id` is always safe (for PHP code which doesn't share a single DB connection between threads). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808337/is-mysql-insert-id-thread-safe .

Comment: @Kitsune please don't take mysql developers as complete fools.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel It has nothing to do with taking them for fools, but of *exactly* what that function does. According to that other question, if the same connection is shared among multiple threads and transactions are *not* used, it WILL return the wrong data in the scenario I outlined. That's important information to have.