# How does mysql_insert_id() works?

Tags: php, mysql

"mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query"

Imagine 3 online users calling the same query, e.g. Insert into table.
User one inserts row into the table, but user no. three will be the last who calls the query, just a few milliseconds after user one.

What will return mysql_insert_id for user one ? Will it be his Id or the Id of the user three ?

And what can I use, if this function is deprecated ?

Comment: l00k right --> where 1000s of this question asked already

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is mysql\_insert\_id thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808337/is-mysql-insert-id-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2):

The insert ID is tracked *per connection*. Without persistent connections, each individual script execution has its own connection. With persistent connections, each Apache process has its own MySQL connection (but each individual process serves results serially - so it's not an issue). As long as you call `mysql_insert_id()` from within the same page load as the `INSERT` query in PHP, you're fine.

To answer the second part of your question, you should be using the `mysqli` or `PDO` (preferred) libraries. `mysqli` has the corresponding `mysqli_insert_id`. `PDO` has a `lastInsertId()` method.

Comment: +1, but disagree with '(preferred)'

Comment: @Mchl just try to bind an array into IN() once, and you'll change your mind immediately.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hahaha. Among various other reasons why PDO is an excellent choice. It abstracts away the implementation specifics. You can switch between underlying databases without having to change your code. You only have to modify the queries that aren't compatible.

Comment: This latter is a just a myth. it's actually impossible to switch between underlying databases without having to change your code. anyway, such a transition is a too rare thing to talk about.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I actually strongly disagree with that because I have personally done it. With no _code_ changes. There were SQL changes, of course. But nothing in PHP was changed. Of course, it depends on what platforms you're switching to and from. No need to continue discussion here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense your preference is not universal preference. I do agree PDO in general is overall easier to use. However you need to be aware of some quirks. For example, when you use named placeholders in prepared statements... you don't actually use prepared statements. PDO just interpolates boud variables into query  string and passes it as a whole to MySQL. You don't get any benefits of actual prepared statements.

Comment: @Mchl aside from the fact that there is no such thing like "prepared statements benefits", PDO is using them all right with named placeholders as well.

Comment: @Mchl Actually, `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is an option in PDO to emulate prepared statements. Feel free to disable it.

Comment: @ColinMorelli: once again - when you use named placeholders (which is what most people do - except for the Colonel), you always get emulated statements, no matter what this option is set to.